# How to save screen output into a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

So I need to create a script and save the info into a text file, and here is what I did:

```
import platform

def bios_version():
    uname_result = platform.uname()
    pl = {}
    pl['BIOS version'] = uname_result.version

    for a, b in pl.items():
        print(a, ":", b)

#The def is working perfectly but I don't know how to save the file.

print(bios_version())
save_path = 'D:/'
name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")

f = open(completeName, "w")
f.write(bios_version())
f.close
```

So it return:

```
f.write(bios_version())
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative, considering other answers:

```
import platform
import os

def write_bios_version(file_name = None):
    pl = {}
    pl['BIOS version'] = platform.uname().version

    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        for a, b in pl.items():
            print(a, ":", b, file=f)

save_path = 'D:/'
name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")
complete_name = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")
write_bios_version(complete_name)
```

Comment: For the def, it works perfectly fine for me. I just have trouble with saving the screen.

Comment: `write() argument must be str, not None"`. When you don't include a `return` statement in a function, by default it returns `None`. You have to change the function code.

Comment: And saying that you want to "save the screen" is a bad term. You actually want to "save" your output (`print` statements), and if you return the `pl` variable from your function `write` will work.

Comment: `print(bios_version())` also prints nothing since you're not returning anything from the function.

Comment: Hi, so i change it as u suggest and it tell me this "f.write(bios_version())
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict"

Comment: Indeed, you must convert from `dict` to `str`. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Hey, It indeed created the file, but it doesn't save the content in to that file ;)

Comment: Had a missing `+`.

Comment: Yes, i saw the missing and fix it but it is still not saving.

Comment: Well, I've changed strategy considering @AkshayJain answer. Tested printing to file. Making it printing to screen would require another `print` call inside the function.

Comment: So @KorDWLO instead of returning a value form the function, you can use the `file` parameter to `print` function to print directly into a file, bypassing the screen.

Comment: Yes, the new code is working for me. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

- I don't understand why you are using loop and why to store that version detail in dictionary. If there is only single value then just store that in variable and directly return the value and just write into file.

#### Code

```
import platform
import os

def bios_version():
    uname_result = platform.uname()
    pl = f"BIOS version: {uname_result.version}"
    return pl

save_path = 'D:/'
name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")
completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")

f = open(completeName, "w")
f.write(bios_version())
f.close
```

#### Output:

```
BIOS version: <<Your version detail>>
```

Comment: HI, thank you for the suggestion. Im a newbie in python so there are a lot of things i still confused with ;)

Comment: Is my solution, make sense to you or not @KorDWLO

Comment: Good catch about the single value. But not so good if he needs more keys in the future.

Comment: Then he will change the code to loop, but for now this is only the best way. At this point he must need to understand when to use which data type and all the stuff.

Comment: hi Jain, the suggestion abut def is good but it is not saving the content of the def

Comment: I've tried @KorDWLO at my machine and it is saving the content into the file.

Comment: Maybe there is some difference between our computers. Thank you for your helping thou :)